# How to use value of textbox from one form to another form?

Tags: c#, windows

Can we access a textbox value of one form in another form?

Answer (score 8):

You can make the text box public for that form. To do this, change the access modifier property in the properties of the text box:

[image]

Or you can create a public property that exposes the textbox's value:

```
public string Foo {
  get { return txtFoo.Text; }
}
```

The latter is probably preferrable if you only need read-only access to the textbox's text. You can add a setter as well if you also need to write it. Making the complete textbox public allows for much more access than you probably want to have in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is pass the `TextBox` to the constructor of the other form, like this:

```
    private TextBox _control;
      public SomeForm(TextBox control)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._control = control;
    }
```

and use the

```
this._control.text = "bla bla";
```